# Android Root Checker, Java Problems

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm making a simple root checker at the start of my application, it works fine provided that you have SuperSU installed but it doesn't work for other Root Managers like KingRoot etc...

I need it to work for any root manager !

I can't see the problem because it just writes a file as a root process and then checks the exit codes.. So hypothetically it should work for any manager, but it doesn't...

Please help me ... The code I'm using

```
try
        { 
            Process p  = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream()); 
            os.writeBytes("echo \"TEST\" > /system/temp.txt\n");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
            os.flush(); 
            try
            { 
                p.waitFor();
                if (p.exitValue() == 1)
                { 

                } 
                else if (p.exitValue() == 0)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDial = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDial.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDial.setTitle("PRE-ROOT CHECK");
                    alertDial.setMessage("You don't have root access ! \nThis is a not going to work !");
                    alertDial.setPositiveButton("                                                                           Exit                                                                           ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });
                    alertDial.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    alertDial.show();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            { 
                System.exit(0);
            } 
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
/**
   * Checks if the device is rooted.
   *
   * @return <code>true</code> if the device is rooted, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   */
  public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
      return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
      File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
      if (file.exists()) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
  }

  // executes a command on the system
  private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
  }
```